# Automated Testing for Android FirebaseUI Auth

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, automated-tests, firebaseui

I want to have some tests for my Android app's login page. I found the [test folder in FirebaseUI auth folder](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth/src/test); However, I don't know how to use it. Any idea?